# Evaluate and log Tensorflow GradientBoostedTreesModel over training with custom metrics

Tags: tensorflow, validation, decision-tree, tensorboard

I want to evaluate tensorflow_decision_forests GradientBoostedTreesModel (Ranking task) along the training steps with my custom validation metrics. In the other tf keras model, I can do this with a custom ValidationSet class as a part to the Callback object which is then passed into .fit, but for GradientBoostedTreesModel, so far I cannot. I found that for this Tree model, the evaluation of my custom metrics happens only once at the end. This seems to be consistent with how the code works:

```
callbacks: Callbacks triggered during the training. The training runs in a
        single epoch, itself run in a single step. Therefore, callback logic can
        be called equivalently before/after the fit function.
```

from https://github.com/tensorflow/decision-forests/blob/main/tensorflow_decision_forests/keras/core.py#L1180.

If anyone has some workaround to manually log validation metrics or any suggestion for this, that would be very appreciated. Thanks!

What I tried:

I have tried .make_inspector() but from my understanding, it is hardcoded to only log ndcg (and loss which is the negative of ndcg)

I tried to train the model multiple times, hoping for evaluation to happen each end of training as a workaround. However, each new training restarts the model from scratch (the log says it compiled again even if I already compiled it) unlike other keras model that .fit continues from the trained model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no built-in way in TF-DF to log custom metrics during training.

TF-DF allows to resume training with the `try_resume_training` option in the model constructor, see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/decision-forests/blob/5e921023e1d6420b8c70f86830c914e0148af733/tensorflow_decision_forests/keras/keras_test.py#L1864) for a usage example. This is probably a workaround for your problem. Keep in mind that (depending on the size of your dataset), this might be slow, since the dataset will be read into memory multiple times.

*Full Disclosure: I'm one of the authors of Tensorflow Decision Forests.*

Comment: Thanks! I am trying with your suggestion now.